# Does casting a virtual IList to IEnumerable in Entity Framework object enumerate?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Consider the below `Order` object as an Entity Framework entity.

If I was to cast an instance of `Order` down to `IOrder`, and then access the `Lines` property on `IOrder`, would that cause the virtual `OrderLines` property to enumerate and load all the `OrderLine` entities from the database, returning a populated collection of OrderLine entities in memory?

Or will the client code just get a reference to the OrderLines collection, which will load the entities from the database once it is actually enumerated such as in a foreach?

```
    public interface IOrder
    {
        IEnumerable<OrderLine> Lines { get; }
    }

    public class Order : IOrder
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }



        public IEnumerable<OrderLine> Lines
        {
            get
            {
                return OrderLines;
            }
        }

        public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }

        public Order()
        {
            OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your questions. It looks like both ask for same thing but are connected with "or".

Comment: Sorry Ladislav, I saw the ambiguity when I re-read it. I've altered the question, so should hopefully make more sense to you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return a reference to the `OrderLines` object, but exposed as `IEnumerable`. Which means that only an enumeration in client code will actually enumerate the the collection. This is the *entire* collection: linq filters (`Where`) and projections (`Select`) will not be translated to SQL.

Note that this neither of these may be desired. First, the context must be alive to allow lazy loading and second, the collection may be 'large' (although with order lines that probably won't be a point). Depending on the type of application it may be better to transfer a pre-populated OrderDto object to the client.

Comment: "Which means that only an enumeration in client code will actually enumerate the the collection." - by this are you saying that each enumeration will lazy load the corresponding entity from the database?

Comment: Yes, that's what will happen, provided that the context is still alive and lazy loading is enabled of course.